# How to define concept of a function that returns bool

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to define a concept of a function that takes in a single argument and returns `bool`. Here is what I came up with:

```
template <typename T>
concept ConditionFunc = requires(T t) {
    { ConditionFunc(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

I want to use it like this

```
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

bool IsEven(int n)
{
    return n % 2 == 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(std::vector<T>& v, ConditionFunc auto func)
{
    // stuff
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Foo(v, IsEven);
}
```

But I am getting an error because the concept requirements are not met. GCC reports that template type `T` that is used to define the concept `ConditionFunc` is deduced to be `bool (*)(int)` but I expected it to be `int`.

How can I define this concept correctly?

Comment: `ConditionFunc(t)` inside of a concept makes no sense, you should be doing `t(…)`. You'll probably need an extra template parameter for the type of the argument to pass to `t`.

Comment: That's usually called a "predicate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept should be based on 2 types, the argument type `T`, and the function type:

```
template <typename Func, typename T>
concept ConditionFunc = requires(T t, Func f) {
    { f(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

Then you can constrain `Foo` to accept a function with the signature `bool(T);`, like this:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(std::vector<T>& v, ConditionFunc<T> auto &func) 
{
    // stuff
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/X7xCg5).

Comment: `Func` should be the first parameter for the concept, that way you can write `ConditionFunc<T> Func`

Comment: @cigien How does ```ConditionFunc<T> auto &func``` work here? I've been looking at concept examples and that doesn't look like code I've seen anywhere else.